# what is the most light antivirus for mini laptop?

Tags: laptop, anti-virus

What is the most light antivirus for mini laptop?

Comment: Maybe this question would be better off being CW.

Comment: With a bit more detail too. Operating System? Free or paid preferred? Maybe even laptop specs.

Comment: Maybe not? memory footprint, used disk space and scan speed are quite easy to determine.

Comment: However, I'm +1 for it is an interesting question. I've a feeling that anti vir. these days slow the machine more then they "help it".

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/16273/which-is-the-best-light-weight-antivirus

Comment: ok, more detail - HP mini laptop, win 7 starter,2G memory,intel atom n280

Comment: @Molly obviously, but what you consider a "small memory footprint" may not be so small if has a very low amount of RAM installed, there may be better options. Scan speed will also vary depending on hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVG Anti-Virus is something that I use on all my PCs. I dunno if it really is "LightWeight" but it does have that feel that it's not even there unless something goes wrong. It's also small and friendly to use.

Answer (score 1):

**[A-Squared Command Line Scanner](http://www.emsisoft.com/en/software/cmd/)** ... ain't nothing 'lighter' or faster.

It includes all functions of the Anti-Malware scanner and both the top scan engines Emsisoft Anti-Malware and Ikarus Antivirus.